# unable to update theme options of Elessi Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I’m using Elessi Theme Version: 4.2.4 By NasaTheme.
I’m not able to update any theme options. only text is written and I'm unable to click any option please check screenshot

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/21104616?key=4b22f69110d9042acb7e23c0186aa2ff

While in the theme documentation they said you can change the theme options.
documentation link

https://elessi-docs.nasatheme.com/single-product/single-product-images/carousel

I need to update theme options, any suggestions why it's happening like this?

Answer (score 0):

You should update your Elessi theme.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).